# is there any way to make a csv or txt file with R with small size as much as possible?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using R to make data ready for ampl. the csv or txt file that I make by R with the following code is very heavy (18 MB).

```
  write.table(df, directory/data.csv)
```

I am wondering is there any productive  way to make a data set with small size as much as possible?

Comment: There are certainly more efficient datastructures than a CSV, or you can compress it as a ZIP archive. Without knowing more about the structure of your data, it's tough to help.

Comment: If your data is sparse (lots of zeroes) then writing it in an AMPL .dat format and using the "default = 0" option may save you a lot of space.

Comment: where I should write default=0?

Comment: @sherek_66 Usually in the declaration of the param; see [section 9.4 of the AMPL Book](https://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/12-data.pdf). I strongly recommend at least skimming through the whole of that chapter to get familiar with the different options for specifying data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are asking this because you want to email it. Here are some of the ways you can compress it
1. try to convert it to binary file 
2. zip it and split it by 10Mb

https://rce-docs.hmdc.harvard.edu/faq/how-do-i-use-compressed-data-r

Comment: I am asking becouse I want to use it as a input file for AMPL (an optimization solver)

Comment: it worked for me, the file's size is small but a column which was numerical has " "  around each number and it shouldn't be like that in ampl.

Comment: You cannot have column names as just numerals. What you are seeing is `'1'`.  To remove that ` `, You need to make your column names as text to remove that escape character.

Comment: then again size will be increase?

Comment: There should be a small size difference.